# Navigating between view controller with search controller search bar hide and show having ui glitch

Tags: ios, swift, uisearchbar, uisearchcontroller

I have used simple `UISearchController` in `UITableViewController`. This has issue when I use search bar in first controller and which is hidden in next or back forth it shows UI glitch.

Here is how it looks>>
[image]

Here is below code for setting up navigation bar.

```
self.extendedLayoutIncludesOpaqueBars = true

let navigationBar = navigationController.navigationBar
let navigationBarTitleTextAttritbutes = [NSAttributedString.Key.foregroundColor: UIColor.white]
navigationBar.titleTextAttributes = navigationBarTitleTextAttritbutes

if #available(iOS 11.0, *) {
    navigationBar.largeTitleTextAttributes = [NSAttributedString.Key.foregroundColor: UIColor.white]
    navigationBar.prefersLargeTitles = false
}
navigationBar.isTranslucent = false
navigationBar.tintColor = UIColor.white
navigationBar.barTintColor = UIColor.purple
```

And For setting search controller used as below

```
self.searchController = UISearchController(searchResultsController: nil)
self.searchController.dimsBackgroundDuringPresentation = false
self.searchController.hidesNavigationBarDuringPresentation = false
self.searchController.hidesBottomBarWhenPushed = true
self.searchController.obscuresBackgroundDuringPresentation = false

let searchBarObj = self.searchController.searchBar
searchBarObj.delegate = self as? UISearchBarDelegate
searchBarObj.placeholder = "Search here"
searchBarObj.isTranslucent = false
searchBarObj.tintColor = .white

if #available(iOS 11.0, *) {

    searchBarObj.tintColor = .white
    searchBarObj.barTintColor = .white
    navigationItem.searchController = searchController
    navigationItem.hidesSearchBarWhenScrolling = true
} else {
    let tintColor = UIColor.purple
    searchBarObj.barTintColor = tintColor
    searchBarObj.layer.borderColor = tintColor.cgColor
    searchBarObj.layer.borderWidth = 1
    if let table = tableview {
        table.tableHeaderView = searchController.searchBar
    }
}
```

Comment: did u resolve the issue?. I have temporarily set hidesSearchBarWhenScrolling property to false so that there is no UI issue, but the search controller is always visible.

Comment: Sorry. Nope issue is still pending

Comment: try using large titles for view controllers in which you have search bars inside navigation bar. it fixed this issue for me.